# Action bar size in custom xml file

Tags: android

I'm not able to find a way to insert the action bar size attribute in my own xml file. Since I'm using Google maps in my activity, I can't use the built-in xml attribute at all in my layout, but I have to call `setPadding()` on the map using the action bar size. Now, I found the way to retrieve the actionBarSize at runtime, but I wonder if I could skip this code completly, inserting the android attribute in my onw xml, for example:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <dimen name="myownsize">@android:attr/actionBarSize</dimen>

</resources>
```

But in this way it doesn't work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: My suggestion didn't work?

Comment: @Athena no sorry, it works only in xml but I can't get it in easy way in the code. Maybe I understood that I'm asking a not possible thing, the attr must be retrived in the code using typedarray but in this case it's not really worth use my own attr, at the end I can use the default one and end of story.

Comment: Sure, using the default attr should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Define a `attr` in your own project. Create `res/values/attrs.xml` and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <attr name="myownsize" format="dimension"></attr>

</resources>
```

In your `res/values/styles.xml`, under your parent theme definition, initialize this attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="myownsize">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
```

Once this is done, you can use `?attr/myownsize` as a dimension:

```
android:padding="?attr/myownsize"
```

Sorry if I too, misunderstood the question.